# print text message to pdf from r

Tags: r

I am running the same command through a range of files which will generate text messages when there are abnormal features in the files. I want to print all the text messages into one single pdf as the coding run. I tried something like below but it did not work. Is there a way to get around, please? I want to see all the text in `print`.

```
pdf("message.pdf")

for(j in 1:10000){
... # There are some checks to do beforehand
print("a") # This is the actual message
}

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write to a text file with `cat` and `sink`:

```
sink("path/to/file.txt")

for(j in seq(1e5)) {
    cat("My message", "\n")
}

sink()
```

Alternatively, you might want to "knit" an Rmarkdown file with your code placed in a code-chunk, which would be one way to go straight to pdf.